# To use a scope or not use a scope rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, People and Vehicles.  Vehicles belongs to People.

I have a report/query that shows which people do not have a vehicle.  Im trying to incorporate it into my rails app so that it runs when someone wants to see this information.  I decided to write a scope for it, but cannot get the scope working properly.  Code is below.  Any ideas?

```
scope :person_has_no_vehicle, -> { joins(:vehicles).where('Vehicles.person_id IS NULL')}
```

Query is below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    People.ID,
    People.nam_first,
    People.nam_last
FROM
    People
LEFT JOIN Vehicles ON People.ID = Vehicles.person_id
WHERE
    Vehicles.person_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `joins` method always performs an `INNER JOIN`, but your original SQL query uses `LEFT JOIN`.

```
scope :person_has_no_vehicle, -> { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.person_id = people.id").where('Vehicles.person_id IS NULL')}
```